# How can I redirect from "domain.com/index.php?subdomain=subdomain" to "subdomain.domain.com" using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect from:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?subdomain=subdomain
```

to

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/
```

using .htaccess

Comment: So... what have you tried?

Comment: @sectus On most mod_rewrite questions 'effort' (as in showing 'code') is not required. It is far more important to be very clear what should happen. Showing code will usually only make that more confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done like so:

```
#Permanent Redirect
Redirect 301 / http://subdomain.domain.com/
```

Note: there is also a temporary redirect which would use the code 302

However, after reading your question more.. Looks like you want to use a header() Location change instead.

Here is how you can do that in PHP:

```
   <?php

    if(isset($_GET['subdomain']) && strlen($_GET['subdomain']) >= 1) {
       $sub = $_GET['subdomain'];
       $url = 'http://' . $sub . '.domain.com';
       header("Location:$url");
    }

    ?>
```

I think that might be more what you are after.
The .htaccess file controls everything inside its directory so if you set a redirect in the root of www.domain.com it will redirect ALL traffic.

Comment: I want to redirect from form get method like:
http://www.domain.com/index.php?subdomain=anything
to
http://anything.domain.com/

Comment: Plug the snippet of code between the php tags at the top of your index.php page.  That will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

On your .htaccess file type in

```
Redirect /example.html http://example.com/newdirectory/
```

Change example with your file/domain, you just
need to adjust it accordingly.

For further clarification,
[Click here](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file?).